# How to add a column without breaking the grid (cxgrid)?

Tags: delphi

I have a cxgrid with data bind and I want to display an extra column that is not showing:

So I use "Customize..." from the cxgrid interface:
[image]

The column selected above, has Visible set as False, that's why is not showing yet;

FieldName: CODIGO_PRIORIDADE

ValueType: Float

I tried to set it to Visible, it doesn't appear in the grid. If I move its position to below or above, it completely breaks my grid, modifying the Name of all the Grid Column to 1 as well, example:
[image]

How can I properly set this new column to the last position of the grid based on data bind without breaking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the column visible using the object `TFloatField` associated to field ***CODIGO_PRIORIDADE*** using:

```
cxGrid1DBTableView1CODIGO_PRIORIDADE.Visible := True;
```

To send the column *"to the last position of the grid"*, you should do it using the visible columns of the grid, with `VisibleColumnCount` property:

```
cxGrid1DBTableView1CODIGO_PRIORIDADE.Index := cxGrid1DBTableView1.VisibleColumnCount;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Added it to the OnPaint of the Form: 
cxGrid1DBTableView1CODIGO_PRIORIDADE.Visible := True;
cxGrid1DBTableView1CODIGO_PRIORIDADE.Index := cxGrid1DBTableView1.ColumnCount; Thank you !!

Comment: @Invisible-Monster 
If possible, use a different method than `OnPaint`. Try with `OnShow`, or in the activation of the `Dataset`. This `OnPaint` method is called many times when painting the components and you probably don't need to call that method that many times.